# Yocto: When is do_configure run or re-triggered?

Tags: yocto

Even with no changes in my recipes, I see that on an incremental rebuild, do_configure is getting re-triggered.
Appreciate any pointers on what can cause this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
bitbake-diffsigs -t your_recipe configure